# Why does my game suddenly lags despite smooth performance few weeks prior?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, gaming

I've played the game (Genshin Impact) for a few weeks and so far it has gone smoothly until yesterday. It suddenly freezes especially in battles, but a few hours earlier it's state was still fine.

I tried reinstalling it but it's still lagging albeit better than the last time.

Here are my device specifications:

Device name:       LAPTOP-5GKRTL5D

Processor:         AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.10 GHz

Installed RAM:     4.00 GB (3.44 GB usable)

Device ID:         3009BC80-9DB9-46DE-9B3E-17D8636C538B

Product ID:         00327-30895-95972-AAOEM

System type:        64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Pen and touch:  Pen support

The game is placed in a drive with currently 757 GB free. Any idea how should I fix this?

Comment: Reinstalling to fix lag was a complete waste of time. You need to define 'lag', graphics, network, etc. On a 4GB RAM machine paging will also be a large influence; you'd be well-advised to never run any other apps at the same time, especially browsers.

Comment: If you look at the [minimum configuration specs for Genshin Impact](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en/news/detail/5284), you'll see it wants 8 GB of RAM. Is there any chance of you adding more RAM to the laptop?

Comment: yeah I think I might be able to add more RAM.